# How to set object null to viewmodel mvc c#

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

i have data
if i linq query that data will get the data or null,
and set to viewmodel.
 if data is null or there is no data, mvc got error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

my code when linq query

```
 var dpas = (from d in db.komputer
                        join b in db.vga on  d.komputerid equals (long?)b.komputerid
                        where d.komputername == id
                        select new detail_t_komputer
                        {
                            komputer = d.komputer,
                            komputername= d.komputername,
                            vga= d.vga,

                        }).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

my viewmodel

```
 var ViewModel = new KomputerVM
            {
                detail_t_komputer= dpas
            };
```

```
public class KomputerVM
    {
        public IQueryable<detail_t_komputer> detail_t_komputer{ get; set; }

    }
```

my db using MS Sql
and using mvc 5.2.7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you rephrase your post as a question.  I'm unsure if you are trying to set an object to null or finding that an object is null when you weren't expecting it to me.  Reading this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will help lay out your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why an IQueryable in KomputerVM class?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<myBigClass> myList = new List<myBigClass>
            {
                new myBigClass() {name = "Pippo", surname = "Poppo"},
                new myBigClass() { name = "Pluto", surname = "Ploto"}

            };

            var dpas = (from d in myList
                        where d.surname == "Ploto"
                        select new myfindclass
                        {
                            name = d.name,
                            myflag = true
                        }).DefaultIfEmpty();

            var ViewModel = new myClass
            {
                myvar = dpas
            };

        }

        public class myClass
        {
            public IEnumerable<myfindclass> myvar;

        }

    }

    public class myfindclass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool myflag { get; set; }
    }

    public class myBigClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
    }
```